# Does Ajax send both ResponseJson and ResponseText over the wire?

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

In my ajax responses i have `responseJSON` and `responseText`. My question merely is, do both come through as part of the response or is the `responseText` derived from the `responseJSON` or visa versa on client side?

Because in my case they are the same, which means the response could have the same data twice. Seems unnecessary and a potential waste of data transfer.

*Not enough street cred to embed images:* [screenshot of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXos3.png)

Thanks,
Gregg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just two different representations that your js client makes available to you. Response only adheres to HTTP standards, as in [this example response message](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPResponseMessageFormat.htm).

As per your question, responseJSON is just responseText after json parsing.

**EDIT**: dataType property docs:

> If `text` or `html` is specified, no pre-processing occurs. The data is
>   simply passed on to the success handler, and made available through
>   the `responseText` property of the `jqXHR` object.
>
> If `json` is specified, the response is parsed using `jQuery.parseJSON` before being
>   passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object
>   is made available through the `responseJSON` property of the `jqXHR`
>   object.

Comment: Thank you, i will mark your answer correct if you can add the following detail from jQuery documentation for `dataType `:

**jQuery Docs** for `dataType ` option:
i.e: `dataType: 'json'`
If text or html is specified, no pre-processing occurs. The data is simply passed on to the success handler, and made available through the responseText property of the jqXHR object.

If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object is made available through the responseJSON property of the jqXHR object.

Comment: Okay i see my formatting has gone faulty :/ . Sorry, url:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sure, here you go.